# Libreswan to Juniper SRX. Tunnel is up and running but nothing is going through

Tags: networking, vpn, juniper

ipsec auto --status says that the connection is established:

```
000 #544: "VPN":4500 STATE_MAIN_I4 (ISAKMP SA established); EVENT_SA_REPLACE in 208s; newest ISAKMP; lastdpd=-1s(seq in:0 out:0); idle; import:admin initiate
```

But I do not see any changes in route table and the destination server does not respond to ping.

What I should check next what might be wrong? I asked from the Juniper admin and he said that tunnel is up but he cannot see the sent ping packets from us.

Comment: Could you add your conf to the question? Be sure to redact the actual IP's,

Comment: version 2.0
config setup
        protostack=netkey
        nat_traversal=yes
        virtual_private=%v4:192.168.17.0/24
conn VPN
     authby=secret
     auto=start
     type=tunnel
     left=10.30.40.150
     leftid=10.20.30.140
     leftsubnet=10.30.40.0/24
     leftnexthop=%defaultroute
     right=10.10.21.21
     rightsubnet=192.168.17.0/24
     rightnexthop=%defaultroute
     ike=aes256-sha1;modp1536
     phase2=esp
     phase2alg=aes256-sha1
     keyexchange=ike
     pfs=yes

Comment: Any ideas for this? Looking with tcpdump I can see that the tunnel itself is able to discuss with the other end but for example ping packets or telnet is not visible in the dump.